# Encoding JSON using ESAPI encoder

Tags: java, esapi

I have encoded JSON (using ESAPI encoder) in the server side.The client then retrieves the fields of the bean and does further processing.

On the server side

```
JSONBean bean=new JSONBean();
//populate the bean
Gson gson=new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(bean);
String JSEscapedStr=ESAPI.encoder().encodeForJavaScript(jsonString);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(JSEscapedStr);
```

Encoded JSON string

\x7B\x22name\x22\x3A\x22Sameer\x22,\x22company\x22\x3A\x22Company\x22,\x22designation\x22\x3A\x22Developer\x22\x7D

On the client side

```
   var JSONObj=JSON.parse(data);
    var name=JSONObj["name"];
    var company=JSONObj["company"];
    var designation=JSONObj["designation"];
    //process these variable in javascript
```

I have also tried using response.setContentType("plain/text"); in the server side which also doesnot work.

Error

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data when content type is "plain/text"

If I hard code the json String then it works

```
            var jsonEncoded="\x7B\x22name\x22\x3A\x22Sameer\x22,\x22company\x22\x3A\x22Company\x22,\x22designation\x22\x3A\x22Developer\x22\x7D";
            var JSONObj=JSON.parse(jsonEncoded);
            console.log(JSONObj);
            var name=JSONObj["name"];
            var company=JSONObj["company"];
            var designation=JSONObj["designation"];
            console.log(name);
            console.log(company);
            console.log(designation);
```

Comment: Get a proxy tool, like Firefox's TamperData extension or get a copy of OWASP's ZAP tool, and trap the response from the server and add it here.

Comment: If you answered your own question, please post the answer, or else kindly provide the requested information.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should only encode the payload (which should already be done bei Gson itself) not the whole JSon tree.
2. `ESAPI.encoder().encodeForJavaScript` is designed to encode params or function arguments for JavaScript-Methods/Functions.

Comment: However encodeForJavaScript produced escape characters like \x2F, which validator's don't like and I also think it's not legal in JSON Strings, it should be \u002F (like in Java). This renders encodeForJavaScript unusable for me. How can we overcome this issue?